# Generic way of updating value in database table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I have a table called CommonData which, as you may suspect, contains data elements that need to be persisted that are in general use throughout the app and will be a table containing a single row.

It has these rows:
    ID (int)
    Threshold (decimal)
    MajorName (string)
    MinorName (string)

There will be more added in due course. I want to create a class that allows updating of a single column except for ID as EF doesn't allow me to create a key-less table.

So far, I have an enumerated type containing these names. So far I have:

```
public class CommonDataEditor : ICommonDataEditor
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<CommonData> _commonDataRepository;

    public CommonDataEditor(IGenericRepository<CommonData> commonDataRepository)
    {
        _commonDataRepository = commonDataRepository;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Edit(CommonDataAttribute dataAttribute, object newValue)
    {
        var row = _commonDataRepository
            .GetAllQueraybleAsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault()
            ;

   }
```

I'm a little stuck. How can I use the "dataAttribute" enum being passed in (which just contains the names of the fields the user can update) and use this to specify the column I want to update with newValue?

Is there a better approach than how I'm doing it?

This is the only table this will happen on. I'd just rather not make separate setters for each individual attribute as they will all be exactly the same. Plus I'm trying to be clever!

Comment: You already must create an enum entry for each field, so why is maintaining an Entity class so much more difficult? It will be less difficult when you factor in the work it will take to get the enum to work.

Comment: I just went with separate methods for each attribute. I was kind of hoping to find some way of just having a class produce a list of allowed types by reflection based on my model and then allowing the UI change values by specifying the type and then value without any code changes.